# Avoiding metastability by sampling a signal

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to VHDL code this circuit below to avoid metastability in my project.

[image]

This is the code that I have written so far:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity Metastability is 
port ( clk : in std_logic;
       key : in std_logic;
       reset : in std_logic;
       Led : out  std_logic
);

end Metastability   ;  

architecture rtl of Metastability is 
    signal metastable : std_logic;
    signal stabel : std_logic;
begin 
    process(clk,reset)
    begin 
        if (reset ='1') then 
            metastable <= '0';
            stabel <= metastable;
            Led <= stabel;
        else if rising_edge(clk) then 

            metastable <= key;
            stabel <= metastable;
            Led <= stabel;
        end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end rtl;
```

But when I simulate it in modelsim the `stabel` signal won't change its state before two clock cycles have passed, and one extra for `Led` to become `'1'`. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: And what is it that is weird and unexpected?

Comment: When i run sim the code  the stable signal wont change it's state before on two clock cycle have passed and one extra for the Led to be '1' . why is that ? I have just added a pic of the sim in the edited question! :)

Comment: Leds aren't normally clocked. So you can simply assign `Stable` to `Led` outside the clocked process and the delay will come down to teh expected 2 cycles.

Comment: What you are describing is a two stage synchronizer. What you get on the output can be considered 'stable'. However, there is still a small chance of metastability, which can be an issue in very high speed or high reliability circuits. There you sometimes need three or more stage synchronizers, to further reduce the change of metastability.

Comment: Thank you guy for your responds! :) Now I think i have a better understanding !

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

#### Reset

On reset you want to assign *fixed* values (known at compile time) to the signals. So you should change

> ```
> if (reset = '1') then
>     stabel <= metastable;
>     …
> ```

to

```
if (reset = '1') then
    stabel <= '0';
    …
```

Otherwise `stabel` is not in a defined state until one clock cycle after the reset has passed.

#### Wrong circuit

The code you've shown doesn't describe the circuit in the picture. Instead it describes a circuit which has one additional register:

```
  key            metastable        stabel           Led
         ,,,,,,,          ,,,,,,,          ,,,,,,,
    ---> | D  Q | ------> | D  Q | ------> | D  Q | --->
         |      |         |      |         |      |
         |>     |         |>     |         |>     |
         ´´´´´´´          ´´´´´´´          ´´´´´´´
```

You should remove the assignment to the `Led` signal from the clocked process and instead make a concurrent assignment:

```
process(clk, reset)
begin
    …
    metastable <= … ;
    stabel <= … ;
end process;

Led <= stabel;
```

---

Also there are two minor issues:

1. The signal name should be spelled `stable`, not `stabel` (but at least you're consistent).
2. Instead of using two nested `if`s, use a single `if` with `elsif`:

   > ```
   > if (reset = '1') then
   >     …
   > else
   >     if rising_edge(clk) then
   >         …
   >     end if;
   > end if;
   > ```

   becomes

   ```
   if (reset = '1') then
       …
   elsif rising_edge(clk) then
       …
   end if;
   ```